# Is there a way to simplify this if else block?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I have this really long if else block and I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it?

```py
def position(self, k):
    
    if self.b == None:
        self.b = k

    if (self.b).location_of(k) == 0:
        if self.aquire(0) == None:
            self.put(0, ABK(k))
        else:
            self.aquire(0).insert(k)
    elif (self.b).location_of(k) == 1:
        if self.aquire(1) == None:
            self.put(1, ABK(k))
        else:
            self.aquire(1).insert(k)
    elif (self.b).location_of(k) == 2:
        if self.aquire(2) == None:
            self.put(2, ABK(k))
        else:
            self.aquire(2).insert(k)
```

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCgIhEIbvPcUcFRaJusSSh7oGvUJYKQ2KuuoeenpzaDOouc0/33x/fJZH8NtdTLXetYEYMhYMnmXtzACWjytogwYoEFfADOfg9TumWXIJ9kOuYS@BuXCDUS5n0TZF3kswzHJOxObraE9MdVpNMyZNggb@9fXOOBdiBjgcT@TshHb5h1cCfdapNKzWFw).

Answer (score 2):

You could store the value of `self.b.location_of(k)` on a variable and use it later to call your functions.

```py
def position(self, k):
    
    if self.b is None:
        self.b = k
    loc = self.b.location_of(k)
    if loc < 0 or loc > 2:
        return  # Return in case the value is out of scope
    if self.aquire(loc) is None:
        self.put(loc, ABK(k))
    else:
        self.aquire(loc).insert(k)
```

Edit:

Olvin Roght pointed out that you can also save the result of the `self.aquire(loc)` call:

```py
def position(self, k):
    
    if self.b is None:
        self.b = k
    loc = self.b.location_of(k)
    if loc < 0 or loc > 2:
        return
    aqu = self.aquire(loc)
    if aqu is None:
        self.put(loc, ABK(k))
    else:
        aqu.insert(k)
```

Comment: If you are using a recent enough python version, you can also use the "new" cool syntax `:=` to make it even shorter and more readable.

Comment: @BlackBeans, this answer is pretty explicit which is good for beginners. It's arguable that [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) somehow increases readability,

Comment: @BlackBeans It's a feature you can only use if you're using [Python3.8 or newer](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) and since it wasn't specified which python version is used I tried to keep it as universal as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As of python 3.8, you can achieve a result similar to the other answers in a shorter manner using the walrus operator (`:=`), more formally known as the assignment expression operator. This sort of inline assignment is similar to the way assignment can sometimes be done in nested `if`s in C:

```
def position(self, k):
    if self.b is None:
        self.b = k
    if 0 <= (loc := self.b.location_of(k)) <= 2:
        if (val := self.aquire(loc)) is None:
            self.put(loc, ABK(k))
        else:
            val.insert(k)
```

In addition to the more obvious changes, I recommend using `x is None` rather than `x == None`, as it is the more idiomatic comparison.